# ExtJS dynamically change object properties, after construction?

Tags: extjs, properties

i have some interesting question about ExtJS framework.

for example, window object in extJS have config option: 'onESC' (some events, when esc key down), and another properties.

I need dynamically loading this property changing (change it on my server and put there).

i need some method, for example, "set" or analog for overloading onESC and all properties of my window object.

--

```
var window1 = Ext.create("Ext.Window", {.... some config here ....});

window1.show();
```

--

so, how change all properties of this object after construction??

has anyone any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mixing a lot of terms its hard to understand all of what your asking "change it on my server and put there" for example

The properties you mention are detailed in the methods list of [Window](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.window.Window). If you want to alter a listener, drop one, add one, etc. Altering / destroying the "all the properties" and not recreating the window isn't easy, depending on how much altering you want to do without actually changing the window.

Comment: Thanks... Can you explain me, how alter, drop "listeners" window in the program code? What methods i must use... I think i want to see example with layout property (that's more actually)